# Operator Linearity

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

How can you prove rigorously that an operator is linear?

For example the momentum operator $p = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ or position operator $x = x$.

Answer (score 0):

You prove an operator is linear by applying the definition of a linear operator.  A linear operator 'O' has the following properties:

- Given two functions, f and g: $O(f + g) = O(f) + O(g)$
- Given a scalar s:  $O(sx) = s\cdot O(x)$

Any operator which has these properties is linear.  Any operator that does not have them is not linear.